# Odd if-else behavior in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple Javascript button to toggle a menu on and off the screen. I have a little if-else statement that detects the current position of the `<nav>` and changes it's `left` css property to that effect.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/todesiqige/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

Now, as you see in my code, this will show the menu once but won't hide it back afterwards:

```
if (navStyle == '0') { setNav('-500px'); }
else { setNav('0'); }
```

And this will do the job properly:

```
if (navStyle == '-500px') { setNav('0'); }
else { setNav('-500px'); }
```

Weird right? Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: did you fix it? jsbin seems to be working for me (Chrome on Win7)

Comment: It may be anything but odd. :)

Comment: You have to un-comment the buggy section in javascript. I kept the working behavior so you could see what's the intended functioning

Comment: Running your JSBin with a few added log statements, we see that `navStyle` becomes `"0px"`, not `"0"`. So `navStyle == '0'` will never be true.

Comment: Both code sections do the same for me on Firefox 11.0/Linux. Also, you have setNav('-0') in the code, but it works the same either way and hides the menu.

Comment: @kojow7 I thought I corrected that before saving but it's not really the problem. I'm surprised that it does work on your system, maybe it depends on browser implementation ?! See the solution below by Duffmaster33

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the width will never actually be equal to 0, it will be something like 0px depending upon the units you choose.  Your second set of conditions work because they check for the width first (500px) and if it doesn't match chooses the other (0px).

You can handle this in a variety of ways, including extracting just the number value from 0px, however since you already have this working, its just something to be aware of in the future. :)

Comment: So Javascript will add the `px` at the end even though I didn't specify?

Comment: Yes, it measures it in whatever the current unit is, px in this case

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try to debug more thoroughly with `alert()` from now on